# How to sort (orderby) a query done by a template function before the 'foreach' loop?

Tags: php, functions, loop, order, sort

How can I sort an array of elements being hold on a query done by a template function, just before the output starts on a foreach loop?
I wanted to order my elements by the Post Title. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$show_subproperties = apushome_get_config('show_property_sub', true);
if (!$show_subproperties) {
    return;
}
$post = get_post();
$author_id = $post->post_author;
$subproperties = Realia_Post_Type_Property::get_properties($author_id, "publish", get_the_ID()); ?>

<?php if (is_array($subproperties) && !empty($subproperties)) : ?>
    <div class="property-subproperties">
        <h3><?php echo esc_html__('Módulos Individuais', 'apushome'); ?></h3>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <?php foreach ($subproperties as $subproperty) : ?>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 modulos-i">
                <?php echo Realia_Template_Loader::load('properties/box', array('property' => $subproperty)); ?>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </div><!-- /.subproperties -->
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what `Realia_Post_Type_Property::get_properties()` does and returns, this is a bit tricky to answer. But essentially, you want to to sort an array using PHP.

Unless `Realia_Post_Type_Property::get_properties()` allows you to get a sorted list of posts, your best bet is probably to use [`wp_list_sort()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_sort/).

That function sorts a list of objects, based on one or more orderby arguments. Assuming `$subproperties` is an array of `WP_Post` objects, you should be able to do the following:

```
$subproperties = wp_list_sort( $subproperties, array( 'post_title' => 'DESC' ) );
```

Comment: hey mate, thank you very much! I finally figured out how to do, I answered below.
You seem to be pretty familiarized with PHP, though... can you help me here, please?

I have an array of arguments, being hold inside $Var. Then, a function() is called (and some posts are queried), passing that var (hence, the whole array) as parameter.
One of these parameters is the limiter of elements queried.
I need to add a parameter inside that array, which is a function to filter the elements according to its resulted boolean value, BEFORE the later function() stops the query because of that limit.

Answer (score 0):

I found a quite simple solution, once I finally realized $subproperties is just a simple array:

```
            <?php asort($subproperties);
        foreach ($subproperties as $subproperty) : ?>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 modulos-i">
                <?php echo Realia_Template_Loader::load('properties/box', array('property' => $subproperty)); ?>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </div><!-- /.subproperties -->
```